# reCAPTCHA implementation on kony

Tags: recaptcha, visualizer, temenos-quantum

I have an issue in implementing reCAPTCHA on my mobile application.
What I have done, write a HTML page with reCAPTCHA sample code then publish the page on a server.
I'm using Kony visualizer, inside the form I put a browser widget, inside this browser load that URL I published before.

Now, my question is in that URL there will be data I have to pass it to my kony app, how is that will be?